# updating Text Box Items in WINAPI

Tags: c, winapi

I created a textbox with following code. It is placed under WM_COMMAND of WNDPROC function.

```
htextbox=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("test"), WS_CHILD \
                         | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 100, 20, 140, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I want to update the element "test" written in the textbox when I receive: DT_MSG which is a message I receive from another application and the DT_MSG contains the item I want to write in the textbox. suppose the item I get is number say

```
int a=dtmsg.somenumber
```

Do I have to delete the above htextbox window and again create new textbox window with updated value or is there alternative and I can simply update `"test"` item in the same text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply do it like this:

```
SetWindowText(htextbox, TEXT("new text"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the text of an Edit Control by using the Win32 API [SetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546.aspx)